# regex get files and subdirectories

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I have `

```
        List<string> paths = new List<string>() {
            @"C:\TestFolder",
            @"C:\TestFolder\SubFolder1\folder3",
            @"C:\TestFolder\SubFolder2",
            @"C:\TestFolder\TextFile.txt",
            @"C:\TestFolder2\hhh\ZZZ",
        };`
```

I would like to receive the files and subdirectories to specific directory.

For example for the directory C:\TestFolder

I would like to get it

- SubFolder1
- SubFolder2
- TextFile.txt

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the list was generated from a search in the file system, MSDN has some good methods:

- [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles.aspx) (Fixed List)
  [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413379.aspx) (Enumerable)
- [`Directory.GetDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getdirectories.aspx) (Fixed List)
  [`Directory.EnumerateDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratedirectories.aspx) (Enumerable)

You can use those, and use [`Regex.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zy662f6.aspx) to test if the file fits your pattern.

If you *are* working from a fixed list, you may want to look in to using [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) (if the file resides on your system) or just [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) and test if the path begins with the directory you're looking for (won't need Regex for that).